# Limiting values in the spinner field

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form with an input field box.here i used a spinner which can be increased or decreased using the buttons on it.Here i need to make value of input field with id spinner within certain limit (like 1-31) (ie,we can't decrease the value below 1 and increase above 31 by clicking spinner button) using jquery or ajax.How should i do that??Please help me.below is my code.

spinner.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Spinner - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/
              jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/resources/demos/external/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner();
                $( "#disable" ).click(function() {
                    if ( spinner.spinner( "option", "disabled" ) ) {
                        spinner.spinner( "enable" );
                    } else {
                        spinner.spinner( "disable" );
                    }
                });
                $( "#destroy" ).click(function() {
                    if ( spinner.data( "ui-spinner" ) ) {
                        spinner.spinner( "destroy" );
                    } else {
                        spinner.spinner();
                    }
                });
                $( "#getvalue" ).click(function() {
                    alert( spinner.spinner( "value" ) );
                });
                $( "#setvalue" ).click(function() {
                    spinner.spinner( "value", 5 );
                });
                $( "button" ).button();
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <label for="spinner">Select a value:</label>
            <input id="spinner" name="value">
        </p>
        <p>
            <button id="disable">Toggle disable/enable</button>
            <button id="destroy">Toggle widget</button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <button id="getvalue">Get value</button>
            <button id="setvalue">Set value to 5</button>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The min and max value are set when the spinner is created. To change them on the fly, use this:**

// given a 'data' object from AJAX with keys 'min' and 'max':

```
$('#spinId').spinner('option', 'min', data.min);

$('#spinId').spinner('option', 'max', data.max);
```

Also keep in mind that the **.attr()** function can only be used to get and set attributes of DOM elements.

For example, you can use it to get or set the id of a  or the href of an  element.

Most jQuery plugins keep their configuration in JavaScript variables.

If they do attach configuration to the DOM, they use **.data().**

Hope this helps..

**Updated:**

The above code snippet is JavaScript and not HTML Code.

Replace the max and min with the values , you want to restrict.

**For example , if you want to restrict between 1 and 31: Then:**

```
  $('#spinId').spinner('option', '1', data.min);

  $('#spinId').spinner('option', '31', data.max);
```

**Updated 2:**

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            var spinner = $( "#spinner" ).spinner();
           $('#spinner').spinner('option', '1', data.min);
            $('#spinner').spinner('option', '31', data.max);

            $( "#disable" ).click(function() {
                if ( spinner.spinner( "option", "disabled" ) ) {
                    spinner.spinner( "enable" );
                } else {
                    spinner.spinner( "disable" );
                }
            });
            $( "#destroy" ).click(function() {
                if ( spinner.data( "ui-spinner" ) ) {
                    spinner.spinner( "destroy" );
                } else {
                    spinner.spinner();
                }
            });
            $( "#getvalue" ).click(function() {
                alert( spinner.spinner( "value" ) );
            });
            $( "#setvalue" ).click(function() {
                spinner.spinner( "value", 5 );
            });
            $( "button" ).button();
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: I don't understand where should i use this code in my html code.Please tell me the complete details

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you because it works for me!

```
$("#spinner").spinner({min: 1, max: 31});
```